# Googlebot attempting to submit every select option in form creating 118,000 404's in webmaster tools

Tags: php, forms, .htaccess, http-status-code-404, googlebot

I have a form on every page of my site that you need to select 4 options from dropdowns before it can be submitted (validated by jquery).

However it appears a googlebot is successfully being able to submit a form looping through each of the options in the first dropdown.

What is more strange is that it is appending the query string on the end of the current Url which is generating 404's. 118,000 to be exact as I have lots of pages where the form is on.

Here is an example of the type of 404's I am getting.
When the form is submitted it should go to /car.php which is in the root of the website, instead it appending it on the end or the current url

[image]

This is my form

```
<form id="getData" action="<?php echo $root; ?>/car.php" method="GET">
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT model_year FROM car_query_models_full ORDER By model_year DESC");
echo "<select name=\"model_year\" class=\"span2\" id =\"model_year\">";
echo "<option>Year</option>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<option value=\"" . $row['model_year'] . "\">" . $row['model_year'] . "</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
?>
  <select name="model_make_display_name" class="span3" id="model_make_display_name">
    <option>-</option>
  </select>
  <select name="model_name" class="span3" id="model_name">
    <option>-</option>
  </select>
  <select name="model_id" class="span2" id="model_id">
    <option>-</option>
  </select>
  <input type="hidden" name="popQuery" id="popQuery" value="y" />
  <button id="buttonSearch" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary span2 pull-right hide">View Car</button>
</form>
```

You can see in the form action that is have a string called $root and then /car.php, the root is just my url eg. www.website.com/car.php.

There is javascript form validation on the site that stops you physically submitting the form until you have selected all 4 options, perhaps googlebot ignores js?

Comment: Google bot parse HTML code not js :) Setup your form to work (when there is no javascript support) and the bot will work fine. (perhaps you may use default values for empty select boxes)

Comment: I had it check if all fields were populated on car.php, if not then 301 to 404.php. But still had those 404's appear in webmasters (even though the page ended up redirecting to 404.php. its a shame i cant check that all the fields are populated, then send submit the form, but of course php cant do that

Answer (score 0):

Google does submit forms with both GET / POST request if they think this will help to crawl contents, they also understand JS and submit request when they see AJAX code in the page. I have a site that Google even submitted email and password via sign up forms multiple times a day. Details here:

http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.hk/2011/11/get-post-and-safely-surfacing-more-of.html